# Dask job causing memory to run out

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

My python code in dask is connecting 3 nodes of 18gb ram 40gb drive but have a memory problem which kills the dask job. The job is basically creating a list from a file of numbers 1-10^9 and then I use scatter to distribute the list data to all three nodes memory. If I remove every coce after this scatter code line, the memory still runs out apparently.
The code is:

```
import dask
from dask.distributed import SSHCluster
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.bag as bag
import os
import dask.dataframe as dd

def checkPrime(n):
    if n == 1:
        return
    if n > 1:
        for i in range(2, n):
            if (n % i) == 0:
                return
    return n

def removeNone(n):
    if n == None:
        return False
    else:
        return True

cluster = SSHCluster(["10.195.4.221", "10.195.6.186", "10.195.6.164"])
client = Client(cluster)

lines=[]
with open("numbers.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = int(line.strip())  # preprocess line
        lines.append(line)

print(len(lines))

mini_data = client.scatter(lines)
prime_output = client.map(checkPrime, mini_data)
result = client.gather(prime_output)

result2 = filter(removeNone, result)


# open file in write mode
with open("output.txt", 'w') as fp:
    for item in result2:
        # write each item on a new line
        fp.write("%s\n" % item)
    print('Done')
```

The job is to calculate prime numbers and save all the prime numbers in a text file after. Any idea how to resolve this?

Following is the output:
[image]

Comment: You're still keeping the list data in local memory, and you're then gathering up a second copy of it.

Comment: @AKX so no distribution is happening? I thought scatter() was supposed to do that

Comment: Distribution _is_ happening, but look at what you're doing after it. You keep `lines` in memory, and then you `client.gather` a new local copy, which you filter locally.

Comment: so I should manually remove lines from memory after scatter()? but how would I then run the map job if I dont have any variable to reference for data? and I thought gather is supposed to accumulate the results from all nodes and bring it back to the master node? if this is just creating a new copy, how else would I get the individual results back from all worker nodes? @AKX

Comment: You can see what happens if you do `del lines` after the `mini_data = ...` line. And yes, `gather` accumulates the results from the nodes, but it does it into memory, so you'll need enough memory for it. I'd recommend rethinking your code into something that will reduce the number of returned values from the remote nodes? [You seem to be importing `dask.bag` but not using it at all?](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/bag.html)

Comment: @AKX I can try that. I am not using dask.bag atm. I can filter in worker nodes and then return back to master node to write the results but I couldnt find a filter function for dask client that can do this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249998/discussion-between-mujtaba-faizi-and-akx).